# Node.js logs a route that is not listed anywhere

Tags: node.js

I am taking a course about Node.js and Angular. I have only two routes registered on Nodejs. All paths that I access is logged at the console screen.

The thing is, I am getting two lines of a log that is NOT in my code, and it seems really strange:

```
GET /user_avatar/localhost/esqueleto/40/1246_1.png 200 5.748 ms - 462
GET /user_avatar/localhost/cristianonasciment/40/3720_1.png 200 7.032 ms - 462
```

As I don't have these routes (or directories) here in my development laptop, does anyone would know what the hell is going on?

Thank you very much.

Comment: well, the response size of the two are identical. Does your error/404 handler return a 200 status code?

Comment: @KevinB what's also common for Angular projects is to have a catch-all route that sends back the `index.html` file for anything that wasn't specifically handled already. It could also be that.

Comment: @robertklep yeah, i'm willing to bet that's it. and something within the angular app is linking to those two urls. or something else linking to them, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Without further information, it looks like you are accessing a publicly visible server and someone else is sending requests to it.

Since the server responded with a `200`, it looks like it thinks you do have that resource and provided it to the requestor.

Try making that request yourself and see what it returns.

Comment: It seems to be more of a request for additional information than an answer.